# Hide standard background when using AlphaImageLoader filter in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

please how to hide standard background image from IE when `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader()` is applied? I am using it for bacground-size support in IE..CSS looks like this

```
    background: url('../img/visit_ok.png') no-repeat center center;
    .background-size(contain);   //LESS mixin   
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
            src='img/visit_ok.png',
            enabled=true,
            sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
            src='img/visit_ok.png',
            enabled=true,
            sizingMethod='scale');
```

The problem is in IE both images are displayed..On top is correctly scaled background form the filter, but underneath is the standard non-scaled png..

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe hide the regular background in an IE only stylesheet. Put this code in the HEAD of your page and either include an IE stylesheet link or put the CSS in there directly on the page.

```
<!--[if IE]>
    Special instructions for IE here
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks..I forgot mention I want to avoid this conditional stylesheets. isnt there better (another) solution?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of I'm afraid.